# Fourier transform and energy of a convolution with a delta comb

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, dirac-delta

Hi guys i have to find the fourier transform of the convolution:
$$ sinc(t/2T)*\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT) $$

i was thinking of express the summatory as : $$\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT) = \mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{T}(t-1)$$
so we have:

$$ sinc(t/2T)*[\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{T}(t-1)]$$

So the convolution in the fourier domain became a product:
$$ rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)-2rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/T}(t)e^{ipif} $$

Well is this a good result and how i can find the energy from this formula  ?

Comment: I think that the simpler approach is to simply rewrite
$$
\mathrm{sinc}(t/2T)*\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT) = 
\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (-1)^n \mathrm{sinc}(t/2T - nT)
$$

Comment: but how can fourier transform that ?

Comment: why it's a sum of 2 dirac deltas ?

Answer (score 1):

$rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)$ is a single Dirac delta so you are almost done. I think you meant  $2\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) - \mathrm{III}_{T}(t)$ where $$\mathrm{III}_T(t)=\sum_n \delta(t-nT)=|T|^{-1} \mathrm{III}_1( t/|T|)$$ whose $e^{-2i\pi f t}$ Fourier transform is $$\mathrm{III}_1( |T| f)=|T|^{-1}\mathrm{III}_{1/|T|}( f)$$

Alternatively you could replace $\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT)$ by its Fourier series (which converges only in the sense of distributions) and change the order of summation obtaining a series of $sinc \ast e^{iat} = \widehat{sinc}(a) e^{iat}$.

Your function is $2T$ periodic, so with the energy you meant $\int_0^{2T} |g(t)|^2dt$ ?

Comment: thk for your answer but i don't understand where the phasor went , i wrote my alternate comb as one comb less another one translated , so the translaten beacme the phasor , right ?

Comment: $\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t)-\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t-1)$ works too but not what you wrote.

Comment: $$ \mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{T}(t-T)$$  maybe i need to write my alternate combo in this way ? but sorry 'm not understaing what you are doing

Comment: and i don't understand how you get you fourer series of that comb , and what's a $$\widehat{sinc}$$

Comment: $\mathrm{III}_T(t)=\sum_n \delta(t-nT)$ right ? Then $\sum_n (-1)^n \delta(t-nT) = \mathrm{III}_{2T}(t)-\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t-1)=2\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) - \mathrm{III}_{T}(t)$. The Fourier series is obtained from $h(t) = \sum_k c_k e^{2i\pi nt/|2T|}$ where $c_k = \frac1{2|T|}\int_{b}^{b+|2T|} h(t)e^{-2i\pi n t/(2|T|)}dt$ (that's how we find the Fourier transform of the Dirac comb). And $\widehat{sinc}$ is the Fourier transform of $sinc$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $$ \sum_n (-1)^n \delta(t-nT) = \mathrm{III}_{2T}(t)-\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t-T)=2\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) - \mathrm{III}_{T}(t)*e^(traslation) $$?

Comment: Yes sorry ${}{}{}$.

Comment: so which is the right way to do it ? @reuns

Comment: the one you prefer, I'm saying that you made some mistakes and that correcting them you'll get one or two Dirac deltas for the Fourier transform of $sinc(t/2T)*\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT)$

Comment: sorry but i'm really struggling to understand the way of doing it..

Comment: The same as you did but without the mistakes;

Comment: $$ sinc(t/2T)*\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT) $$ 

i was thinking of express the summatory as : $$\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT) = \mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{T}(t-T)$$
so we have:

$$ sinc(t/2T)*[\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{T}(t-T)]$$ 

So the convolution in the fourier domain became a product:
$$ rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)-2rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/T}(t)e^{ipiT} $$   So this is the right way ?

Comment: $sinc(t/2T)*[\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t) -\mathrm{III}_{2T}(t-T)]$  and $rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)-2rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)e^{2 i\pi T}$

Comment: ok thank you so much and just one little thing.. how can i get the energy ? the think that is blocking me is the phasor

Comment: $rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)-2rect(f2T)\mathrm{III}_{1/2T}(t)e^{2 i\pi T}$ is a sum of two Dirac deltas, inverse Fourier transforming you'll get a much simpler expression for  $sinc(t/2T)*\sum\limits_{n-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\delta(t - nT)$

Comment: i get 1+ $$\delta(t - nT)$$  , right ?